# How to Save as PDF with A4 paper size document using chrome options settings in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am automating printing feature so I need to set my printing settings in printing preview dialog but I don't find the attributes to use for some settings..

```
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>() {{
put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[]{"Chrome PDF Viewer"});
put("printing.default_destination_selection_rules", "{\"kind\": \"local\", \"namePattern\": \"Save as PDF\"}");
}],\"version\":2,\"isGcpPromoDismissed\":false,\"selectedDestinationId\":\"Save as PDF\"}");
put("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState", "{\"recentDestinations\": [{\"id\": \"Save as PDF\", \"origin\": \"local\", \"account\": \"\" }],\"version\":2,\"isHeaderFooterEnabled\": true,\"paperSize\": 'A4',\"isGcpPromoDismissed\":false,\"selectedDestinationId\":\"Save as PDF\"}");
}});
```

I also used media size parameter as following:

put("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState", "{"recentDestinations": [{"id": "Save as PDF", "origin": "local", "account": "" }],"version":2,"isGcpPromoDismissed":false,"selectedDestinationId":"Save as PDF","mediaSize": {"height_microns": 355600,"width_microns": 215900,"is_default":true}}");

But still not reflected.

Please help if there is a documentation for printing settings..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.